# fread() of file from archive

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to know what is the recommended way of reading a `data.table` from an archived file (zip archive in my case). One obvious option is to unzip it to a temporary file and then `fread()` it as usual. I don't want to bother about creating new file, so instead I use `read.table()` from `unz()` connection and then convert it with `data.table()`:

```
mydt <- data.table(read.table(unz(myzipfilename, myfilename)))
```

This works fine but `read.table()` is slow for big files while `fread()` can't read `unz()` connection directly. I'm wondering if there is any better solution.

Comment: You might take a look at the `read_file` function from the `readr` package (one of Hadley Wickham's).  I've found it to be faster than base R reads for unzipped files and the documentation indicates that it can read zipped files.

Answer (score 28):

Look at: [Read Ziped CSV File with fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644556/using-fread-to-import-csv-file-from-an-archive-into-r-without-extracting-to)
To avoid tmp files you can use unzip with -p extract files to pipe, no messages

You can use such a kind of statements with fread.

```
x = fread('unzip -p test/allRequests.csv.zip')
```

Or with gunzip

```
x = fread('gunzip -cq test/allRequests.csv.gz')
```

You can also use grep or other tools.

Comment: It's worth adding when preprocessing command is used `data.table` developers recommends using `cmd` arg, e.g. `fread(cmd = 'unzip -p test/allRequests.csv.zip')` due to security reasons.

Comment: I had to copy my `unzip.exe` file to my working R directory for this to work.

Comment: unzip or gunzip have to be in $PATH.